# Unable to display URL in WebView from another view controller

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UITableViewController that needs to open a web view.

In my function I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

                LinkViewController *linkViewController = [[LinkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LinkViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

                [linkViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];

                [self.navigationController pushViewController:linkViewController animated:YES];

}
```

I have connected all outlets and am not getting any warnings however I do not see the page pull up.

However if I go in the actual LinkViewController file and do something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj]; 
}
```

everything seems fine. I do not understand why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a `URL` property to your `LinkViewController`. Then in your table view controller you do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LinkViewController *linkViewController = [[LinkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LinkViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];             
    linkViewController.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:linkViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Now in your LinkViewController you do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.URL];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj]; 
}
```

There are two problems with what you had originally:

1. In the table view controller, you were accessing the `webView` property before it was initialized. This is why nothing happened.
2. You were exposing far too much implementation detail of the `LinkViewController` to the outside world. If you use `LinkViewController` in many places in your app, you are requiring every user of the class to know to create a URL, create a request, and then tell the internal web view to start loading. All of that logic belongs inside the `LinkViewController`. Now each user of the class only needs to know to set a simple URL property.

Comment: one of the most detailed answers. Your approach worked. Thanks much