# Swift 2 - Cannot load UIWebView in separate ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I'm running into a bizarre problem - I cannot load a `UIWebView` in the background of a separate viewcontroller. Specifically, I have a `UITableViewCell` with a button to load a UIWebView in the viewcontroller behind it. However, I keep getting the error "found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"...

Here is my code:

```
func loadWebView(URLString:String) {

    print("the urlstring is \(URLString)")
    let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: URLString)
    let theRequest = NSURLRequest (URL: theRequestURL!)

    fullScreenWebView.loadRequest(theRequest)


}
```

The print statement yields the correct URL, so the issue isn't that the URL string isn't being passed.

Furthermore, if I load the `UIWebView` from the viewcontroller it's defined in, it works perfectly. I'm guessing the issue has to do with not being the correct viewcontroller when `loadWebView()` is called... I read [Unable to display URL in WebView from another view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180498/unable-to-display-url-in-webview-from-another-view-controller), which was somewhat helpful.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us how you are keeping a reference of the `UIViewController` with `UIWebView`. Have to initialized `fullScreenWebView`?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? im doing everything as normal except im just calling the UIWebview from another place

Comment: I mean, you have initialized the web view in **controller A**, but you are calling `loadRequest` in **controller B**. So how are you passing the reference of the view controller to **Controller B**?

Comment: oh ok gotcha... im doing SecondViewController().loadWebView("URL STRING HERE")

Comment: And are you presenting the new view controller modally or pushed on a navigation stack?

Comment: im pushing it on a nav stack. why am i getting a nil value tho?

Answer (score 1):

When calling `loadRequest` using

`SecondViewController().loadWebView("URL STRING HERE")`

You are creating a new instance of the *SecondViewController* rather than using the one that has already been loaded.

What you need is call `loadRequest` on the instance that is already in memory, and has your `UIWebView` initialized.

For this you can get reference of the previous view controller and call a method to load your request

*Assuming SecondViewController is the controller with UIWebView*

Add this In the top view controller (Controller with your `UITableView`)

```
func loadWebView(URLString:String) {

    print("the urlstring is \(URLString)")
    let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: URLString)
    if let theRequest = NSURLRequest (URL: theRequestURL!) {

        //In case you push view controller on a navigation stack
        let vc : SecondViewController = self.backViewController()

        vc.loadWebView(theRequest)
    }
}

//Get previous view controller on navigation stack
func backViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if let stack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
        for(var i=stack.count-1;i>0;--i) {
            if(stack[i] == self) {
                return stack[i-1]
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Now in your *SecondViewController*, add

```
func loadWebView(request : NSURLRequest) {

    // Replace customWebView with the reference variable of your `UIWebView`
    customWebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: still getting same error. im trying to call the webview from a tableviewcell. does that make any difference?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code of how you are calling it from a Table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are force unwrapping a nil value. I would always suggest unwrapping nullable values using an `if let` statement:

```
func loadWebView(URLString:String) {

    print("the urlstring is \(URLString)")
    if let theRequestURL = NSURL (string: URLString) {
        let theRequest = NSURLRequest (URL: theRequestURL!)

        fullScreenWebView.loadRequest(theRequest)
    }
}
```

Not every string can be converted into a URL, which is why `NSURL(string:)` returns a optional value. I would inspect why your URLString can't be parsed into a URL

Comment: right, but i know that these urls work. as mentioned in the question, the webview works fine when called from the viewcontroller. it just doesnt work when called from the tableviewcell